# How can I do nested joins in hql

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I currently set my entities in Hibernate using OnetoMany joins within my entities. I need to pull InvTran documents nested within my InventoryReceiptsLine Result. My issue is that I don't want to add data to these tables this way and rather setup a custom query to pull this type of report. My goal is to get the following output where the invTran populates if there is an existing order assignment to InventoryReceiptLine.

```
{
    "receipt_number": 5000027,
    "items": [
        {
            "receipt_number": 5000027,
            "inv_mast_uid": 22428,
            "qty_received": 100,
            "unit_of_measure": "EA",
            "item_id": "TRI620-104-706",
            "item_desc": "HSS104 CLAMP 4-8/64\"-7\"",
            "invTran": []
        },
        {
            "receipt_number": 5000027,
            "inv_mast_uid": 13628,
            "qty_received": 200,
            "unit_of_measure": "EA",
            "item_id": "DIXHSS72",
            "item_desc": "ALL STAINLESS WORMGEAR CLAMPS",
            "invTran": []
        },
        {
            "receipt_number": 5000027,
            "inv_mast_uid": 22412,
            "qty_received": 100,
            "unit_of_measure": "EA",
            "item_id": "TRI620-008-706",
            "item_desc": "620-008 CLAMP (HAS 8)",
            "invTran": [
                {
                    "transaction_number": 4245,
                    "document_no": 1000064,
                    "qty_allocated": 51,
                    "unit_of_measure": "EA",
                    "inv_mast_uid": 22412,
                    "oe": null,
                    "receipt_id": 5000027
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried setting up my repository as follows to eliminate the need for the OneToMany join on the InvTran object but I get the following error

"*Cannot read field "value" because "s1" is null [SELECT IHDR FROM com.emrsinc.patch.models.InventoryReceiptsHDR IHDR left join fetch InventoryReceiptsLine IRL on IRL.receipt_number = IHDR.receipt_number left join fetch InvTran on InvTran.sub_document_no = IRL.receipt_number WHERE IHDR.receipt_number = :receipt]*"

when building by query as

```
@Query(value = "SELECT IHDR " +
            "FROM InventoryReceiptsHDR IHDR " +
            "left join fetch InventoryReceiptsLine IRL on IRL.receipt_number = IHDR.receipt_number " +
            "left join fetch InvTran on InvTran.sub_document_no = IRL.receipt_number " +
            "WHERE IHDR.receipt_number = :receipt")
    InventoryReceiptsHDR getReceipt(@Param("receipt") int receipt);
```

Inventory ReceiptsHDR class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "inventory_receipts_hdr")
public class InventoryReceiptsHDR implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer receipt_number;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "receipt_number")
    @JsonProperty("items")
    private Set<InventoryReceiptsLine> inventoryReceiptsLineList;


}
```

InventoryReceiptsLine class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "inventory_receipts_line")
public class InventoryReceiptsLine implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonBackReference
    private Long line_number;

    private Long receipt_number;
    private Long inv_mast_uid;
    private Long qty_received;
    private String unit_of_measure;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "inv_mast_uid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private InvMast invMast;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "inv_mast_uid", referencedColumnName = "inv_mast_uid"),
            @JoinColumn(name="sub_document_no", referencedColumnName = "receipt_number")
    })
    private Set<InvTran> invTran;

}
```

InvTran class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "inv_tran")
public class InvTran implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer transaction_number;
    private Integer document_no;
    private Integer qty_allocated;
    private String unit_of_measure;
    @JsonProperty(value = "receipt_id")
    private Integer sub_document_no;
    private Integer inv_mast_uid;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_number", referencedColumnName = "order_no")
    private OeHDR oe;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is an ad-hoc join and you can't fetch entities this way, you need a DTO.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(InventoryReceiptsHDR.class)
public interface InventoryReceiptsHDRDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    Set<InventoryReceiptsLineDto> getInventoryReceiptsLineList();

    @EntityView(InventoryReceiptsLine.class)
    interface InventoryReceiptsLineDto {
        @IdMapping("line_number")
        Long getId();
        Long getReceipt_number();
        @Mapping("InvTran[sub_document_no = VIEW(receipt_number)]")
        Set<InvTranDto> getInvTran();
    }
    @EntityView(InvTran.class)
    interface InvTranDto {
        @IdMapping("transaction_number")
        Integer getId();
        Integer getDocument_no();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`InventoryReceiptsHDRDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, InventoryReceiptsHDRDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<InventoryReceiptsHDRDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: This is really helpful and I was able to define a receipt view using EntityView and a Repository that extend EntityViewRepository. My only issue is that I don't know where to put the configuration for CriteriaBuilderFactory. Should I define a class called BlazeConfig and add the @Configure annotation to it?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. Also see the setup guide which mentions a dedicated class for this: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-setup

Comment: I was able to set it up and query the InventoryReceiptsHDR class but am unable to nest InventoryReceiptLine I know there's mappings on the entity view but do I also have to declare a OneToMany join within the entity itself?

Comment: You can either refer to associations implicitly through name or explicitly through the use of `@Mapping`, or you write out the join condition explicitly like in `getInvTran`. Since you posted an entity that contains `inventoryReceiptsLineList`, I assumed that your real model has the same association, hence I named the getter `getInventoryReceiptsLineList` to match up with the association name.